# Best structure for key-value pairs with extra time information

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I currently have an entity in MongoDB that has a list of key-value pairs (see "metadata" below). What I am wanting to do now is to allow multiple values for each key, with the option of a begin and end time associated with each value. A simple array of key-value properties fit the model previously but would it still make sense to keep all data embedded like it is proposed below? Efficiency of reading and filtering on the key and time quickly is more important than writing.

As I am slowly getting the hang of NoSQL, any help is welcome. Thanks!

Currently:

```
"metadata" : [ 
{
    "key" : "Weather",
    "value" : "Sunny"
}, 
{
    "key" : "Temperature",
    "value" : "24"
}]
```

Proposed:

```
"metadata" : [ 
{
    "key" : "Weather",
    "value" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "Sunny",
            "time" : {
                "begin_time" : "09:00",
                "end_time" : "12:00"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "Cloudy",
            "time" : {
                "begin_time" : "15:00",
                "end_time" : "17:00"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "key" : "Temperature",
    "value" : "24"
}]
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's "best" without showing what types of queries you've tried, and how they match with the performance and technical requirements you have. The structure you have may be fine, but I couldn't say without seeing the queries/aggregations you'll want to use.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of something along the lines of queries like -  db.entity.find({"metadata.key": "Weather", "metadata.value": {$elemMatch: { "value": "Sunny", "time.begin_time": "09:00" }}})

Comment: How big would you arrays grow? The potential problem here is that the find() result will be the entire document. If these documents can grow large then you may want to consider having a document per value given it works for any other use cases you may have.